# Why does the InputStream of a socket returns -1 only when the socket is closed?

Tags: java, sockets, inputstream

I have read on some question of StackOverflow that we usually use the condition `(c = inputStream.read()) == -1)` to detect if "end of stream" is reached. However, I've also read that the OutputStream of a socket only sends an "end of stream" message if the socket is closed.

This makes this server code...

```
public class Server {
    public static int port = 27018;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        char c = ' ';

        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        System.out.println("Server started");
        Socket connectionSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        serverSocket.close();
        String bufferOuputString = "";

        InputStream in = connectionSocket.getInputStream();
        OutputStream out = connectionSocket.getOutputStream();

        System.out.println("Connection established on port " + port);
        out.write("Welcome to my server !".getBytes());


        System.out.println("Waiting for client messages");
        while(c != '/'){
            c = (char) in.read();
            if(c == '*'){
                System.out.println(bufferOuputString);
                bufferOuputString = "";
            } else {
                bufferOuputString += c;
            }
        }

        connectionSocket.close();
    }
}
```

...alongside this client code...

```
public class Client {
    public static int port = 27018;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try (Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", port)) {
            int c;
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            String bufferInputString = "";
            String bufferString = "";

            OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
            InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();

            while((c = in.read()) != -1){
                bufferInputString += (char) c;
            }
            System.out.println(bufferInputString);

            while(!bufferString.contains("/")){
                System.out.println("You can write messages to server:");
                bufferString = sc.nextLine() + "*";
                out.write(bufferString.getBytes());
            }
        }
    }

}
```

... useless. Because the client awaits for the end of stream signal (`in.read() = -1`) that never comes, so it stays blocked by the `InputStream.read()` call.

For the record, I tried this as server code to further check this "rule" of sockets:

```
public class Server {
    public static int port = 27018;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        char c = ' ';

        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        System.out.println("Server started");
        Socket connectionSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        serverSocket.close();
        String bufferOuputString = "";

        InputStream in = connectionSocket.getInputStream();
        OutputStream out = connectionSocket.getOutputStream();

        System.out.println("Connection established on port " + port);
        out.write("Welcome to my server !".getBytes());
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        connectionSocket.close();
    }
}
```

And after 3 seconds, client printed...

[image: Client output]

...and proceeded to go into infinite looping because I forgot to change the second `while` loop. So this confirms that socket's `OutputStream` object only sends "end of stream" at `Socket.close()`. My question is : **why this design choice ?**

Comment: If OutputStream can send 'end of stream' _before_ socket close, then what does that mean? That the socket is closed without calling `close()`? Who decides when that happens? Does it mean the other side gets -1 back for it` `read()` call, but data can later be sent anyway?

Comment: Closing a `Socket` (or its `OutputStream`) sends a `FIN` packet to the peer. This is a *graceful* disconnect. No more data can be sent after `FIN` is sent. The `InputStream` of a `Socket` returns -1 when that `FIN` packet is received.

Comment: @rzwitserloot But does “end of stream” really means “stream is closed” ? Or does it mean “end of current stream of information” and the OutputStream  object is still usable for further communication ?

Comment: Ah, but then that requires a protocol that has a way to communicate 'stream is closed'. It can't be some simple value because you'd want to send _all possible byte values_ on this channel, therefore, there is no one value we can decree to mean 'end of stream'. The solution that _you_ implement a protocol and decide on some sequence of bytes that means 'end of stream'.

Comment: Because that's what 'end of stream' *means.* It does not mean 'end of *current* stream of information'. There is no such concept in TCP and no expression of it in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to close this question.

My conclusion is that the only way to know the end of a message at socket level is really the socket closing. This is because "socket" is at OSI level 5: in TCP/IP, the "end of a message" is indeed the end of the connection. That's why the socket signals "end of connection" only when connection is closed.

The level of abstraction required to identify and separate messages inside a socket's stream must be done at Application level (OSI level 7, typically HTTP), TCP/IP cannot do it by design.

So the solution for this problem is either to define a "end of message" character (like CRLF or `\r\n` in a Java String), or to use an existing application protocol (like HTTP) to exchange messages. From a discovery and experimentation POV, I find that both are interesting!

I realize now this question was more a misunderstanding of the OSI layers than a Java problem. Thank you for taking the time to answer me!

Answer (score -1):

> *I've also read that the OutputStream of a socket only sends an "end of stream" message if the socket is closed.*

Not by default.

There doesn't appear to be anything within the *Socket* class that will transmit a *-1* value.
Here is the source for *[Socket#close](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/fdd3941121aad3975c7b448bb11e50f9943b7af7/src/java.base/share/classes/java/net/Socket.java#L1565)*, and here is *[ServerSocket#close](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/net/ServerSocket.java#L746)*.

The *-1* is sent by the *[read](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/fdd3941121aad3975c7b448bb11e50f9943b7af7/src/java.base/share/classes/java/net/Socket.java#L954)* method, when it has reached the end of the data stream.

So, It would depend on the interface—for example, an *[FTP](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc959.html)* makes use of a *\r\n* sequence to denote the end of a transmission.
The concept is to increase the congruency between the components, since data transmission is *"expensive"*.
Additionally, it's similar to how an *HTTP* header contains a *[content-length](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.3.2)*—this reduces, what some refer to as *[polling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polling_(computer_science))*—essentially, *while((c = in.read()) != -1)*, without the block.
*[Blocking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blocking_(computing))* is a more logical concept, to prevent a requirement to *poll*.

> *... Because the client awaits for the end of stream signal (in.read() = -1) that never comes, so it stays blocked by the InputStream.read() call.*

Correct.
The *Socket* is accessing the *SocketInputStream#read* method, which will block if it there is no data.

Comment: "Not by default' is false. That is *exactly* and *only* when a socket sends 'end of stream'. This happens not in `Socket.close()` but in the TCP stack. `read()` does not 'transmit' a -1, it *returns* it. Answer is largely nonsensical.

Comment: @user207421, I don't understand what you're saying.  Provide an answer maybe.